# DNS record not found after testing

Tags: dns, reverse-dns, dmarc

I am checking my website on mxtoolbox.com and getting some DNS errors. Two of those errors say "DNS Record not found". One has dmarc as category and the other is category spf.

My questions:

1. Does this hurt my website?
2. How do i go about fixing this?

My website is http://www.zilvertron.com

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Note for people coming here after checking their SMTP server : check `example.org`, not `smtp.example.org`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, neither of those things will directly hurt your website, though they may cause you problems with sending email if the recipients score harshly in any spam management application.

There is some info on DMARC [here](https://dmarc.org/overview/) and some info about spf [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) They are both used to help validate that messages are 'allowed' to be send from your domain & hosts and that your domain is who it says it is.

If you wanted to fix/add the records you need to have a look in your dns providers control panel and see what options they support, and how to implement them. Spf is easy - it's just a text record, DMARC/[DKIM](http://www.dkim.org/) requires a bit more setup.